# javascript regex for whitespace or &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a javascript regex for whitespace.
I am checking several different string in a loop and I need to locate the strings that have the big white space in them.

The white space string is built in a loop, like this...

please read this code as `var whitespace = "&nbsp;"` then the loop just concats more non breaking spaces on it.

```
var whitespace = "&nbsp;"

        for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            whitespace += "&nbsp;"
        }
```

then it is used later on in a string concat.

```
sometext += whitespace + someData;
```

I need to identify the strings that contain whitespace (20 spaces).

Or should I just be doing a `contains(whitespace)` or something similar.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined whitespace as 20 spaces, you can do

```
var input = whitespace + someData;
if(input.indexOf(whitespace) != -1)
{
   //input contains whitespace.
}
```

There is no need to use regex when you can do without it.

Comment: Thanks Yogi!! By the way, how do you get my questions so fast? Whenever I ask a regex question, you answer it very quick. Is it twitter related or something? I was just curious. ~ck

Comment: There is a questions feed on SO. Just set your RSS reader to it. :-)

Comment: I get an email whenever you post a question! ;) Just kidding.

I log in to SO every few hours and see if there are any questions which I can answer.

Comment: Also, I looked at your past questions and it seems like you haven't accepted answers for quite a few of them. It will be nice if you can mark the answer which helped you solve the problem.

Comment: I thought Twitter was likely a way of broadcasting the question. I need to sub to the RSS feed. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 53):

For this specific question, Yogi is correct--you don't need regex and you're probably better off without it.

For future reference, if anyone else comes looking, regex has a special character for whitespace:

```
\s
```

In JS parlance (where regex literals may be enclosed in forward slashes) if you're looking for 20 spaces (not tabs, line feeds, etc.) you can do this:

```
/ {20}/
```

You'll also want to note that many browser regex engines do not consider the non-breaking space to be whitespace. The unicode representation for the NBSP character is:

```
\u00A0
```

Combined, looking for any combination of 20 whitespace characters (including tabs, etc.) OR NBSPs in a row (the square brackets denote a 'character class'):

```
/[\s\u00A0]{20}/
```

**EDIT**: Incorporating thomas' point about NBSP. Give his comment and/or answer an up-vote if you would--I know I have.

Comment: one could think so, but actually this is just plain wrong for too many browsers.

Comment: Brilliant! The unicode code point for NBSP is exactly what I was looking for. This is useful for breaking a string into words: `sentence.split(/[\s\u00A0]+/)`.

Answer (score 14):

At least **IE and Chrome do NOT include char 160** (nbsp) in **\s**. A regex that includes it is

```
wsregex = /[\s\u00A0]/
```

see also
http://www.adamkoch.com/2009/07/25/white-space-and-character-160/
who reports about IE, but meanwhile chrome apparently also changed to not include it.

Answer (score 1):

For IE (I tested in IE7), `\s` does not match `&nbsp;` but Chrome and Firefox does. So if you want to eliminate white spaces but not `&nbsp;`(no break space), do not use `\s` as it is not browser safe.

For example, you want to eliminate all white spaces including \n \t but not `&nbsp;`, you can use `\n \t` and white space, that is:  `str.replace(/[\t \n]+/g, "")`

Answer (score 0):

```
text.replaceAll(/(\s[a-zA-Z]) /gm, '$1&nbsp;')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.