# Regex for a special character with only space as a chracter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have JQuery plugin to allow/not allow the special characters and I have been using regex method to allow some special characters like this **-_*@#$%&,."\'?;:**

But now I don't want to allow any special characters but only white space as a special character. How can I achieve it using the regex method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript regex for whitespace or &nbsp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168660/javascript-regex-for-whitespace-or-nbsp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to match just a regular space `' '` you can just escape the space character `'\ '`. If you need to match any whitespace character you can use the special character `\s`which will match any whitespace character such as space `' '`, tab `\t`, newline `\n` or carriage return `\r`.

Check the following examples.

Regular spaces `/\ /g`:
http://regexr.com/3gng6

Any whitespace character `/\s/g`:
http://regexr.com/3gng3